# I have two master pages for admin it is different and user is different but if user copy & paste the URL he can find the page information

Tags: asp.net

I have two master pages in a Three Tier Architecture project.
For admin it is different and for user it is different but if user copy & paste the URL he can find the page information.
Give me a solution please..

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep the user type in `session` after login. And on the particular page check the user type.

If not matching found redirect to login page.

### **or**

broader solution is you need to implement Role Management of asp.net.
[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k850zwb.ASPX)

Some useful links

1. [Admin role management in ASP.NET website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380646/admin-role-management-in-asp-net-website)
2. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667152/Role-Providers